# GetAsyncKeyState() for MS DOS

Tags: c++, dos, borland-c++

I made a small game for Windows which uses GetAsyncKeyState(). Now I want to compile the game for MS DOS, but I cannot find any alternative for this function. getch() and kbhit() are too slow for handling the keystrokes.
The main goal is to handle the keystrokes at the speed of light or at least like with the speed of GetAsyncKeyState().
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www8.cs.umu.se/~isak/snippets/keywatch.c

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems extremely helpful, but borland c++, when I try to compile this program, says 
**cpp 130 at signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN): cannot convert 'void (*)()' to 'void (*)(int)'**
Could you, please, give me some kind of direction what I should do to make this program run? I guess it is for C, that is why I can't compile it. What should I do? Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Are you actually targeting MS DOS, or are you referring to the console subsystem, as part of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

An example code for keyboard handling on Borland c++ MSDOS 
that uses `conio.h` , `kbhit()` and `getch()`. This should compile
just fine in the MSDOS Borland c++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dos.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE (!TRUE)
#define TEXTSCREEN 0xB800


#define esc    27
#define tab    9
#define up     72
#define down   80
#define left   75
#define right  77
#define home   71
#define cend   79
#define pgup   73
#define pgdn   81
#define ins    82
#define del    83
#define plus   43
#define subt   45
#define mult   42
#define devi   47
#define spc    32
#define f1     59
#define f2     60
#define f3     61
#define f4     62
#define f5     63
#define f6     64
#define f7     65
#define f8     66
#define f9     67
#define f10    68
#define ap     53
#define bksp   8
#define enter  13
#define crum   245


void key2(void);

int main(void)
{

    ch=0;
    while(ch!=esc)
    {

       key2(); 

     }

  return 0;
}


void key2(void)
{
  if (kbhit())
  {
    ch=getch();

    if (ch==f1)
    {

    }
    if (ch==f2)
    {

    }
    if (ch==f3)
    {

    }
    if (ch==f4)
    {


    }
    if (ch==f5)
    {


    }
    if (ch==f6)
    {


    }
    if (ch==f7)
    {


    }
    if (ch==f8)
    {


    }
    if (ch==f9)
    {

    }
    if (ch==f10)
    {


    }


    if (ch==tab)
    {

    }

    if (ch==ins)
    {

    }

    if (ch==del)
    {
    }

    if (ch==bksp)
    {



    }

    if (ch==enter)
    {


    }

    if (ch==spc)
    {

    }
    if (ch==49)
    {



    }
    if (ch==50)
    {



    }

    if (ch==up)
    {


    }

    if (ch==down)
    {


    }
    if (ch==home)
    {



    }
    if (ch==cend)
    {



    }
    if (ch==pgup)
    {



    }
    if (ch==pgdn)
    {



    }
  }
}
```